# Between Eclipse IDE and Android Studio, which is more preferable for appium automation?

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, appium

Between Eclipse IDE and Android Studio, which is more preferable for appium automation ?

Which is more easy to configure with Appium?
Which is more advantageous for testing android apps?

Answer (score 0):

Use Ecllipse IDE which will be fast than Android Studio. When you run from Studio it will takes time to build the gradle for the test suite.